# Java, split a String by various tags and store it into a Map

Tags: java, regex, dictionary, split, itext

I have a requirement, create a kind of markdown tags to put **bold `[N]`** and *italic `[C]`* text in a given string when creating `PDF's` with `IText`.

So, given this string:

```
String toCheck = "Example [N]bold text[N] other example [C]italic text[C]";
```

Should result:

> Example **bold text** other example *italic text*

---

Well, let's go:

I have an enum with font types:

```
private enum FontType {
    BOLD, ITALIC, NORMAL
}
```

To achieve that I want to create a `LinkedHashMap<String, Enum>` to insert the String fragments with the corresponding font type (this will be latter transformed to `com.itextpdf.text.Chunk` and inserted into a single `com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph`.

So how can I achieve the `LinkedHashMap` result like this??

```
pos String            enum
0   "Example "        NORMAL
1   "bold text"       BOLD
2   " other example " NORMAL
3   "italic text"     ITALIC
```

I created a custom `Iterator` that gives me the tag position:

```
public class OwnIterator implements Iterator<Integer> 
{
    private Iterator<Integer> occurrencesItr;

    public OwnIterator(String toCheck, String[] validPair) {
        // build regex to search for every item in validPair
        Matcher[] matchValidPair = new Matcher[validPair.length];
        for (int i = 0 ; i < validPair.length ; i++) {
            String regex = 
                    "(" +    // start capturing group
                    "\\Q" +  // quote entire input string so it is not interpreted as regex
                    validPair[i] +  // this is what we are looking for, duhh 
                    "\\E" +  // end quote
                    ")" ;    // end capturing group
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
            matchValidPair[i] = p.matcher(toCheck);
        }
        // do the search, saving found occurrences in list
        List<Integer> occurrences = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < matchValidPair.length ; i++) {
            while (matchValidPair[i].find()) {
                occurrences.add(matchValidPair[i].start(0)+1);  // +1 if you want index to start at 1 
            }
        }
        // sort the list 
        Collections.sort(occurrences);
        occurrencesItr = occurrences.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext()  {
        return occurrencesItr.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        return occurrencesItr.next();
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        occurrencesItr.remove();
    }

}
```

I already checked if tags are balanced, and I can get all tag positions:

```
String[] validPair = {"[N]", "[C]" };
OwnIterator itr = new OwnIterator(toCheck, validPair);
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(itr.next());
}
```

But after getting all the positions can't figure out how to discriminate each portion and assign the correct enum value.

Some ideas? 
Maybe I'm wrong in my approach or someone can see a better one?

Comment: Have you thought of using regular expression groups? check http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/regular_expressions/capturing_groups.shtml#.VopabPl97cs for example.

Comment: @RatshiḓahoWayne if you take a look into the Iterator, regular expressions are already used... you mean in another way? I'm quite bad using regex :$

Comment: Regex would please too complicated, please see the answer I posted instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following piece of code will give you the desired `LinkedHashMap`,

```
private Map<String, FontType> getMapFromTags(String toCheck) {
    Map<String, FontType> chunksMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    boolean openTag = false;

    while (toCheck.contains(TAG_NEGRITA) || toCheck.contains(TAG_CURSIVA)) {
        final int indexOfBold = toCheck.indexOf(TAG_NEGRITA);
        final int indexOfItalics = toCheck.indexOf(TAG_CURSIVA);

        final int indexToUse = getValidIndexToUse(indexOfBold, indexOfItalics);

        final String substring = toCheck.substring(0, indexToUse);
        toCheck = toCheck.substring(indexToUse + 3, toCheck.length());

        if (!substring.isEmpty()) {
            if (!openTag) {
                chunksMap.put(substring, FontType.NORMAL);
            } else if (indexToUse == indexOfBold) {
                chunksMap.put(substring, FontType.BOLD);
            } else {
                chunksMap.put(substring, FontType.ITALIC);
            }
        }

        openTag = !openTag;
    }
    // check if there is some NORMAL text at the end
    if (!toCheck.isEmpty())
        chunksMap.put(toCheck, FontType.NORMAL);

    return chunksMap;
}

private int getValidIndexToUse(int indexOfBold, int indexOfItalics) {
    if (indexOfBold > -1 && indexOfItalics == -1)
        return indexOfBold;
    else if (indexOfItalics > -1 && indexOfBold == -1)
        return indexOfItalics;
    else 
        return indexOfBold > -1 && indexOfBold < indexOfItalics ? indexOfBold : indexOfItalics;
}
```

But there will be issues when you find two or more equal strings that has to be hashed.

Comment: NICE! there is a mistake when the string starts with a tag.... but thanks a lot... :)

Comment: Yes... Apologies, I have modified the code to make it work even when the String starts with a tag.

Comment: Hi @Ratsi, please, kindly check the updates in the answer, there was some other problems with the `indexToUse` when some tag was missing. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
...
String toCheck = "Example [N]bold text[N] other example [C]italic text[C]";
toCheck = replacePairs(toCheck , "[N]","<b>", "</b>");
toCheck = replacePairs(toCheck , "[C]","<i>", "</i>");

OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("Test.pdf"));
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
document.open();
HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(toCheck));
document.close();
file.close();
...

private String replacePairs(String input, String tag, String openTag, String closeTag) {
    String output = input;
    while(output.indexOf(tag) >= 0) {
        output = output.replaceFirst(tag, openTag);
        if (output.indexOf(tag) < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Missing closing tag:" + tag);
        }
        output = output.replaceFirst(tag, closeTag);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Disclaimer: This is uncompiled and thus untested code. You will want to handle exceptions and close your resources properly in the finally block (or using try-with-resources).

Comment: sorry, but this answer completely ignores my question, as I told, I use `iText` thus `<b>` and `</b>` and other format tags does not help in this case. If so, I just need to teach users to use HTML tags, which, unfortunatelly is not an option because wont work in iText.

Comment: My answer uses `com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker` and leverages the existing support for text markup based on HTML. You might not want to do it this way, but I think it works and is much simpler than what you have so far.

Comment: well... `HTMLWorker` is deprecated, `XMLWorker` project is not free, **AND** as far I've checked, cannot be applied to single paragraphs, I was able to create a formatted PDF with an HTML string, but I cannot apply this to a single piece, so I should change all PDF creation (cells, paragraphs etc) to an HTML formed PDF.... what does not seem a good option (too much time)....

Comment: `XMLWorker` is free as long as you follow the terms of the AGPL.